# Could - Past ability or Polite offer

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am an English learner. I came across below sentence, which shows the use of "**Could**" as Polite offer.

***I could lend you my car till tomorrow***.

Is below sentence correct if I want to express my past ability?

***I could lend you my car.***

If yes, then what makes a sentence  "Past ability" or "Polite offer"? Is it **time reference** e.g. **Till tomorrow** in the above sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure "politeness" is relevant to your example, where ***could*** simply conveys that the stated action is something you're able to (and thus *might*, but also, *might not*) do - as opposed to ***will***, which more positively ***asserts*** the certainty of the future action. You're mixing this context up with the distinction between ***Could / Would** you help me?* and ***Can / Will** you help me?*, where the former is less "assertive", so it's considered more "deferential, hedged, polite".

Comment: If you want to express your ***past*** (but ***not current***) ability, *I **could have lent** you my car*. Which would require a specific context if continued with ***...till tomorrow***, but there's nothing particularly unusual about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show "past ability" in the second context, you would want "I could have lent you my car yesterday (but today I cannot)." The second part is optional and could be implied.

You could also use this construction if you want to contrast:

"I could loan you the car yesterday, but today I need it/I can't/it's in the shop." (This would make more sense in response to a setup like "You said yesterday that you could loan me the car!" "Yesterday, I could. Today, I cannot." Some strict grammarians might insist that this should still be "could have" instead of "could", but colloquially, I hear and see "could" here alone all the time.)

If you write "I could loan you my car.", could here is giving a present possibility, and depending on context could be an open offer "If you need a ride, I could loan/lend you my car." a conditional offer "I could lend you my car if you fill it up." or even a refusal "I could lend you my car, but I don't trust you enough." In this last, it states the *possibility* of the action, while the second phrase says that you won't be acting on that possibility.

The "past capability" construction of could is almost always used in a context where the timeframe is stated or implied by the surrounding context.

You wouldn't see "I could swim." as past capability, but as a statement of a possibility right now. "But I'd rather not." for example. It means "This is something I could do right now but might not."

For past capability, it would be "I could swim when I was younger." or the like, meaning "I used to be able to".